# Show the window with the help of pyqtSignal doesn't work

Tags: python, pyqt

I create a window and immediately after launch hide it and show another window. There's a button in that another window, clicking that should show the main window but the program crushes.

Here I send signal to show the main window:

```
class Launcher(QWidget):
    signal = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, signal, parent=None):
        super(Launcher, self).__init__(parent)
        self.signal = signal
        ... # Here's a button
    def click(self): # slot for the button
        self.signal.emit()
```

Here I set slot to get the signal and show the window:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    signal = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.hide()
        self.window = Launcher(self.signal, self)
        self.window.show()
        self.signal.connect(self.showWindow)
    def showWindow(self):
        self.show()
```

Comment: There's no need to pass anything to the launcher. All you need is: `self.window = Launcher(); self.window.signal.connect(self.showWindow)`. You can also get rid of the signal defined in the `MainWindow` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Launcher(QWidget):
    signal = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, signal, parent=None):
        super(Launcher, self).__init__(parent)
        self.signal = signal
        ... # Here's a button
    def click(self): # slot for the button
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("Launch"))

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    signal = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.hide()
        self.window = Launcher(self.signal, self)
        self.window.show()
        self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("Launch"), self.showWindow)

    def showWindow(self):
        self.show()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Python\test.py", line 35, in <module>
        window = MainWindow()
      File "D:\Python\test.py", line 27, in __init__
        self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("Launch"), self.launch)
    AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'connect'

Comment: AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtCore' has no attribute 'SIGNAL'

Comment: @JoeDoe sorry thats the answer for pyqt4

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you `hide()` the parent `MainWindow` automatically the child `Launcher` is also hidden.

One more thing, if `Launcher` emits the signal, `MainWindow` does not need to have the same signal, you just have to capture it.

This is a minimal example of what I think you're looking for:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton

class Launcher(QWidget):
    signal = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Launcher, self).__init__(parent)
        self.btn = QPushButton('Show', self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.btn.show()

    def click(self): # slot for the button
        self.signal.emit()

class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, signal, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.hide()
        signal.connect(self.showWindow)

    def showWindow(self):
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    launcher = Launcher()
    window = MainWindow(launcher.signal)
    launcher.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```